# Powershell Date format

Tags: powershell

I am trying to display the date in the same format which is shown when '`date`' is typed and pressed enter but its showing in a different format. 
Example:
$d = date , when give $d it shows - `Thursday, April 11, 2019 10:57:59 AM`, however when I do `write-host $d` it shows `4/11/2019 10:57:59 AM`, However, I want to retain the original format only (`Thursday, April 11, 2019 10:57:59 AM`). How to achieve it?

Comment: It's unclear what your requirements are and coding questions are better suited for StackOverflow. For instance it's unclear whenever you need to use `$d` later on or not as a date object. Depending on that something as easy as `(Get-Date).toString()` would be sufficient.

Comment: I store date in a variable $d=date. When I do write-host $d it prints in 4/11/2019 10:57:59 AM,  format , But i need to print the date -Thursday, April 11, 2019 10:57:59 AM this format

Comment: Yes and the `toString` would let you save just the output but as mentioned it's unclear whenever that would be sufficient or not. You could also pass a custom format string. In addition it's odd that you'd get different outputs. Instead of just using date use the proper `Get-Date` and check it's help.

Comment: To further work with datetime data it's better to keep it as a [datetime] type, Write-Host seems to format [datetime] by default as a short date time string while otherwise you get the long variant.. If `$d` isn't needed for calculations use `$d = date | Out-String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
write-host $d.tostring('D')
```

Reference: [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-long-date-d-format-specifier)

Keith